# Prepend an item at the beginning of each element of an Eloquent collection of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a collection like this

```
[
  {
    "objective_id": "26",
    "objective_weight": "50.00",
    "objective_description": "This is first strategic objective",
    "actions": [
    ]
  },
  {
    "objective_id": "27",
    "objective_weight": "12.00",
    "objective_description": "This second strategic objective",
    "actions": [
    ]
  },

]
```

**Now I want to add an item for each element of the collection.** *e.g:*

```
[
  {
    "foo" : "bar"
    "objective_id": "26",
    "objective_weight": "50.00",
    "objective_description": "This is first strategic objective",
    "actions": [
    ...
    .....
```

I have tried with `prepend()` method of Eloquent but did not succeed.

```
$new = $objectives->map(function($objective) {
    return $objective->get()->prepend('hello', 'world');
});

return $new;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*but did not succeed*"? Did it prepend anything, did it prepend at the worrying level, or something else?

Comment: Here's what I tried:

$new = $objectives->map(function($objective) {
 return $objective->get()->prepend('hello', 'wordl');
});

return $new;

Comment: Could you edit your question rather than adding a comment? I ask because it's easier for others to see what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those items are just objects and you can add a property by just setting it:

```
$new = $objectives->map(function($objective){
    $objective->foo = 'bar';
    return $objective;
});
```